# ZF2 form doesn't validate because of input filter

Tags: php, zend-framework2

In ZF2, I have a controller whose action works with the form like this

```
if ($request->isPost()) {
    $this->organizationForm->setInputFilter(new OrganizationFilter());
    $this->organizationForm->setData($request->getPost());
    if ($this->organizationForm->isValid()) {
        // further logic to process
```

The `InputFilter` `OrganizationFilter` is this

```
class OrganizationFilter extends InputFilter
{
public function __construct()
{
    $this->add([
        'name' => 'id',
        'filters' => [
            ['name' => 'Int'],
        ]
    ]);

    $this->add([
        'name' => 'name',
        'required' => true,
        'filters' => [
            ['name' => 'StripTags'],
            ['name' => 'StringTrim'],
        ],
        'validators' => [
            [
                'name' => 'StringLength',
                'options' => [
                    'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                    'min' => 3,
                    'max' => 160
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]);
}
}
```

If I comment the line `$this->organizationForm->setInputFilter(new OrganizationFilter())`, the form gets validated, but with this line, it doesn't work.

How to get it validated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out why my code didn't work, but I solved it in another way. For the form with inputs to be validated, I implemented `InputFilterProviderInterface`. Then in the form, `getInputFilterSpecification()`

```
public function getInputFilterSpecification()
{
    return [
        'name' => [
            'required' => true,
            'filters' => [
                ['name' => 'StripTags'],
                ['name' => 'StringTrim'],
            ],
            'validators' => [
                [
                    'name' => 'StringLength',
                    'options' => [
                        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                        'min' => 3,
                        'max' => 160
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
    // other inputs to filter
    ];
}
```

defines all the inputs to be validated. With this implementation, I don't have to set the filter explicitly in the controller, just call `$this->form->isValid()` and magic happens. :-)